# How to Add Stacktrace or debug Option when Building VSCode Project

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

When I run the emulator while using vscode, I get an error like this. What can I do?

````
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org```
````

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because of the path of the project. Change your project path with a way which don't contain non-ASCII character.

For example С:\Android\PROJECT-FOLDER.

1. First run flutter doctor, to see if everything is okay
2. Then run flutter clean, to have a fresh start
3. If that doesn't work check the name of the path and try not to use special characters by that I mean, use English.
4. Or do a workaround and create a new project and copying the files to the new project, as I said before, stick to English, as a Spanish speaker I've run into the same issues before.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was searching for a solution for one day now! And -> cmd -> direct to the flutter projekt folder and run flutter clean helped perfect. Thank you so much!